# Sqlite query on windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, sqlite

i have this piece of code

```
    premios pre = new premios() { name = "premio1", link = "http://www.host.com/image.png" };
                if (DB.CheckPremios(pre))
{//does stuff
}
```

and the CheckPremios function is this one:

```
public bool CheckPremios(premios pre) 
        {
            using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
            {
                var existing = db.Query<premios>("select * from premios where name =" + pre.name);
                if (existing != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

> Additional information: no such column: premio1

it complains that the column "Premio1" doesn't exist, altho "Premio1" ins't the column name...

is my query wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your query call is incorrect, primarily because you haven't enclosed the query value in quotation marks, so SQLite will treat it as comparing against a column name. Rather than adding single quotes in yourself, I'd suggest instead using the query call by specifying where substitutions are to be made and passing in a list of parameters, as such:

```
var existing = db.Query<premios>("select * from premios where name = ?", pre.name);
if (existing != null)
{
    return true;
}
```